# How to set sub frame that always open at main frame position

Tags: java, swing

I have created one main frame and one sub frame for that main frame.

Now that two frames open in my window at center position but, if I close that sub frame and move that main frame now click that icon for that sub frame that time it was open same center position.

I want it to open in the current main frame moving position. How can I do that?

Comment: Use a `CardLayout`, It will provide equivalent functionality, but easier and better and will only require a single `JFrame`. BTW - don't forget to ask a question.

Comment: Are you talking about JFrame ? If yes, take a look at setLocation, as described in https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/index.html?java/awt/Window.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I have create one main frame and one sub frame

First of all an application should only have a single frame. For child windows you should be using a `JDialog`.

> if i close that sub frame and move that main frame now click that icon for that sub frame that time it was open same center position

So the logic in your `ActionListener` should be something like:

```
childDialog.setLocationRelativeTo( parentFrame );
childDialog.setVisible( true );
```

Using the above logic the dialog's location will always be determined just before the dialog is made visible.